# Does a for loop add another object to the scope chain in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I watched this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHtdZgou0qU yesterday, and I've been thinking about how to improve my javascript. I'm trying to keep everything he said in mind when re-writing an animation that looked really choppy in firefox.

One of the things I'm wondering is if `for` loops add on to the scope chain. Zakas talked a lot about how closures add on to the scope chain, and accessing variables outside of the local scope tends to take longer. With a `for` loop, since you can declare a variable in the first statement, does this mean that it's adding another scope to the chain? I would assume not, because Zakas also said there is NO difference between `do-while`, `while`, and `for` loops, but it still seems like it would.

Part of the reason I ask is because I often see, in JS libraries, code like:

```
function foo(){
    var x=window.bar,
        i=0,
        len=x.length;
    for(;i<len;i++){
        //
    }
}
```

If `for` loops did add another object onto the chain, then this would be very inefficient code, because all the operations inside the loop (assuming they use `i`) would be accessing an out-of-scope variable.

Again, if I were asked to bet on it, I would say that they don't, but why then wouldn't the variables used be accessible outside of the loop?

Comment: Variables declared inside `for` loops get hoisted anyway, so there's no reason to explicitly declare them up front.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript does not have block scope and it has variable hoisting, so any variables that appear to be defined in a `for` loop are not actually defined there.

The reason you see code like provided in your example is because of the hoisting behaviour. The code's author knows about variable hoisting so has declared all the variables for the scope at the start, so it's clear what JavaScript is doing.

Comment: Alright, that's what I assumed after seeing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236206/one-var-per-function-in-javascript, but why then are the variables not accessible outside of the loop?

Comment: Although personally I think it's confusing to put the loop's initialiser in the `var`... I always do `var i;` but keep the `i=0` in the `for(...)`...

Comment: @Walkerneo Any variables that appear to be defined inside of a loop *are* accessible outside the loop.

Comment: @alex, Wow, I really had no idea you could do that. Thanks!